# Reduce the use of foreach in array when checking null values php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like below:

```
 $data = array (
        'department1' =>array(
            'user1' => array(
                'building1' => array(
                    'room1' => array(
                        'active' =>'false'
                    ),
                    'room2' => array(
                    )
                ),
                'building2' => array(
                    'room4' => array(
                    ),
                    'room3' => array(
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    );
```

What I am trying to do is to check the room if is null or not. If null I should set a value `active => test`.
The code I've done so far is:

```
 foreach($data as $departments => $department){
      foreach ($department as $users => $user){
         foreach($user as $buildings => $building) {
            foreach($building as $key => $value){
                  if ($data[$departments][$users][$buildings][$key] == null) {
                  $data[$departments][$users][$buildings][$key]['active'] = 'test';
                  }
            }

         }
      }
    }
```

It's working but I want to know if there is a best other way to implement it without used much foreach.

My output is:

```
 Array
 (
[department1] => Array
    (
        [user1] => Array
            (
                [building1] => Array
                    (
                        [room1] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => false
                            )

                        [room2] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => test
                            )

                    )

                [building2] => Array
                    (
                        [room4] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => test
                            )

                        [room3] => Array
                            (
                                [active] => test
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)
Any help? Thank you.

Comment: can you check array_walk_recursive php function?

Comment: If the hierarchy inside the array is fixed, then there certainly is no more effective approach to scanning the array. If the hierarchy varies however, then a fixed stacking of loops won't work and you have to implement an array walk approach. Not more efficient, only more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following recursive function which is accepting and returning value by reference(can be used with any item deepness/hierarchy):

```
function &checkRoom(&$data) {
    foreach ($data as $k => &$v) {
        if (strpos($k, "room") === 0 && empty($v)) $v = ["active" => "test"];
        if (is_array($v)) checkRoom($v);
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = checkRoom($data);
print_r($data);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [department1] => Array
        (
            [user1] => Array
                (
                    [building1] => Array
                        (
                            [room1] => Array
                                (
                                    [active] => false
                                )

                            [room2] => Array
                                (
                                    [active] => test
                                )
                        )

                    [building2] => Array
                        (
                            [room4] => Array
                                (
                                    [active] => test
                                )

                            [room3] => Array
                                (
                                    [active] => test
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk_recursive()` to walk through your `$data` array without having to foreach on each level of depth.

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$value, $key) {
    if (is_null($value) && $key == 'active') {
        $value = 'test';
    }
});
```

The above code example will walk through your `$data` array and change each item with key 'active' that has value 'NULL' to value 'test'.

Note that the 'active' key has to be set in order for this to work.

#### Resources

- [array_walk_recursive() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)